# Libcurl get response "415 Unsupported Media Type" But working well using Curl.exe

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I'm not sure what I did wrong but when using the command in curl no error occurs. It's keep change my type to `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` even though had declared `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-Type: application/json");`
Here is my code:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://zone1:50000/user/login");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    const std::string raw_json = R"json({ "username": "admin", "password": "password123"})json";

        Json::CharReaderBuilder builder {};
        auto reader = std::unique_ptr<Json::CharReader>( builder.newCharReader() );
        Json::Value root {};
        std::string errors {};
        const auto is_parsed = reader->parse( raw_json.c_str(),
                                              raw_json.c_str() + raw_json.length(),
                                              &root,
                                              &errors );
        if ( !is_parsed )
        {
            qDebug() << "ERROR: Could not parse! " << errors.c_str();
        }
        Json::FastWriter fastWriter;
        std::string output = fastWriter.write(root);
        qDebug() << "Parsed JSON:" << output.c_str();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,output.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Origin: https://zone1:50000");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-Type: application/json");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Referer: https://zone1:50000/login");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Connection: keep-alive");
    res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST, cookies);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

The curl command that success:

```
curl --cookie cookie.txt -k -g "https://zone1:50000/user/login" -H "Origin: https://zone1:50000" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "Referer: https://zone1:50000/login" -H "Cookie: JSESSIONID=Fn1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data-binary "{\"username\":\"admin\",\"password\":\"password\"}"
```

The response I receive:

- Found bundle for host zone1: 0x11ce588 [serially]
- Can not multiplex, even if we wanted to!
- Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host zone1
- Connected to zone1 (10.1.233.120) port 50000 (#0)
  *> POST /user/login HTTP/1.1
  Host: zone1:50000
  Accept: */*
  Accept-Encoding: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
  Content-Length: 44
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- upload completely sent off: 44 out of 44 bytes
- Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
  < HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
  HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
  < Connection: keep-alive
  Connection: keep-alive
  < X-Powered-By: Webserver
  X-Powered-By: Webserver
  < Server: Webserver
  Server: Webserver
  < Content-Length: 0
  Content-Length: 0
  < Date: Sun, 08 Nov 2020 06:39:25 GMT
  Date: Sun, 08 Nov 2020 06:39:25 GMT

Answer (score 1):

you're setting the headers all wrong, the header list for CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER is not a char*, it's a special kind of list, try

```c
struct curl_slist *list = NULL;
list = curl_slist_append(list, "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9");
list = curl_slist_append(list, "Content-Type: application/json");
list = curl_slist_append(list, "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*");
list = curl_slist_append(list, "Referer: https://zone1:50000/login");
list = curl_slist_append(list, "Connection: keep-alive");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, list);
(...)
curl_slist_free_all(list);
(...)
```

also don't use CURLOPT_HEADER to set `User-Agent`, because if in the future you do multiple requests, or if you use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, curl will "forget" the user-agent, instead use CURLOPT_USERAGENT, so curl doesn't forget it:

```c
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36");
```

Comment: still having same result

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with adding

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
char* jsonObj = "{ \"username\" : \"admin\" , \"password\" : \"password123\" }";
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,jsonObj );
```

Thanks @hanshenrik for pointing out create list for headers.